# How can I fade in and fade out audio in just_audio?

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I have a ConcatenatingAudioSource for which I want to fade each item in and out. What is the best way to fade in and fade out in just_audio?

Comment: I don't think there is a provided way to do that in the just_audio package yet. What I think you can do is to programmatically reduce the player volume during the transition. Like when the player position is 10 secs from the track duration, then reduce the volume as the player progress. It might work

Comment: Take a look about it [here](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/467)

Comment: @ShaanMephobic thanks this comment on that issue helped give me an idea of what to do https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/467#issuecomment-786366534

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Intellect's comment, I achieved a fade out effect by just controlling the volume with a CountdownTimer. Here is an example in an AudioManager class I set up that does the trick, FYI.

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

class AudioManager {

/// Relevant code snippets ....

  final AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();
  CountdownTimer? _timer;

  Future<void> play({required String audio, required volume}) async {
    _player
        .setAsset('assets/audio/$audio.mp3')
        .then((value) async {
       

      /// Stop the [_player] and important to cancel the [_timer].
      /// If audio is switched, and the [_timer] is not cancelled, it will continue to run and 
      /// may cancel the new clip.
      if (_player.playing) {
        _timer?.cancel();
        await _player.stop();
      }
          
          /// Make sure to reset the volume when play another clip.

      await _player.seek(Duration.zero);
      await _player.setVolume(volume);
      await _player.play();
    });
  }

  Future<void> fadeOutAndStop(
      {required double startVolume}) async {
    /// Will fade out over 3 seconds
    Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 3);

    /// Using a [CountdownTimer] to decrement the volume every 50 milliseconds, then stop [AudioPlayer] when done.
    _timer = CountdownTimer(duration, const Duration(milliseconds: 50))..listen((event) {
      final percent = event.remaining.inMilliseconds / duration.inMilliseconds;
      setVolume(percent * startVolume);
    }).onDone(() async {
      await _player.stop();
    });
  }

  Future<void> setVolume(double volume) async =>
      await _player.setVolume(volume);
  ///
}
```